Headset mic (external) not working with 6.9 and 6.10 kernel
Here's the issue.
When using the 6.9 or the 6.10 kernel system doesn't see an external mic from the headset (3.5 jack). Instead, there's only an internal mic available.
When using the 6.8 kernel or less it's okay, I can use mic from the headset.
Using pipewire, alsa and wireplumber. codec is Realtek ALC285, also have cirrus logic inside (cs35l41).
What iI've tried:

Play with snd_hda_intel model parameters from there:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html?highlight=headset+mic
ex: options snd_hda_intel model=dell-headset-mic
Retask jack with hdajackretask
Install a fresh system on another ssd (latest PopOS) - after kernel update to 6.9.x (from the repository) it's the same issue.

Laptop Model: Asus ROG G14 GA402XY
Codec: Realtek ALC285 + Cirrus logic cs35l41
OS: Debian Testing
Kernel: 6.9.x, 6.10 represents the issue, 6.8.x no
DE: Gnome 46, wayland

Also found that with new kernels there modules loaded snd_hda_scodec_component and snd_soc_cs_amp_lib, but those 2 are not represented with 6.8 kernel.
In pavucontrol panel external headset mic is marked as "unplagged".
Sound packages versions ('pipewire|wireplumber|alsa'):
alsa-topology-conf 1.2.5.1-3
alsa-ucm-conf 1.2.12-1
gstreamer1.0-pipewire 1.2.1-1
libpipewire-0.3-0t64 1.2.1-1
libpipewire-0.3-common 1.2.1-1
libpipewire-0.3-dev 1.2.1-1
libpipewire-0.3-modules 1.2.1-1
libwireplumber-0.5-0 0.5.5-1
pipewire-alsa 1.2.1-1
pipewire-audio 1.2.1-1
pipewire-bin 1.2.1-1
pipewire-pulse 1.2.1-1
pipewire 1.2.1-1
wireplumber 0.5.5-1

cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Nvidia GPU a4 HDMI/DP
Codec: ATI R6xx HDMI
Codec: Realtek ALC285

In journalctl and dmesg there's no difference between 6.8 and 6.9.
